How do you make pip install gdal work?

I'm not talking about pip install precompiled wheel from https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels/releases/tag/v2024.9.22.
I'm not going to use conda or any other methods to install gdal.
I just want to know how do you make pip install gdal work.
I'm using Windows, python 3.12
So my understanding is that pip install gdal doesn't install gdal itself, it only installs Python bindings for gdal. So you need gdal already installed? Is that how it works?

Error I'm getting
PS C:\Users\SJ\Desktop\Programs\Python\pythonProject> pip install gdal                                                               
Collecting gdal
  Downloading gdal-3.10.tar.gz (848 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 848.1/848.1 kB 18.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: gdal
  Building wheel for gdal (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for gdal (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [150 lines of output]
      C:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wd1vnuyg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\_apply_pyprojecttoml.py:79: SetuptoolsWarning: `extras_require` overwritten in `pyproject.toml` (optio
nal-dependencies)
        corresp(dist, value, root_dir)
      Using numpy 2.2.1
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2tiles.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2xyz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalattachpct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalmove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_calc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_edit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_fillnodata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_pansharpen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_proximity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_retile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_sieve.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\ogrmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\ogr_layer_algebra.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\pct2rgb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\rgb2pct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\array_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\batch_creator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_palette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\extent_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\numpy_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\osr_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\progress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\raster_creation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\rectangle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\assemblepoly.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\build_jp2_from_xml.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\classify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\crs2crs2grid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\densify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\dump_jp2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\epsg_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\esri2wkt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fft.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fix_gpkg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2wld.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal2grd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalbuildvrtofvrt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalchksum.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalcopyproj.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalfilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalident.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalimport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdallocationinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_auth.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_cp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_create_pdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_ls.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_lut.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_mkdir.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_remove_towgs84.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rmdir.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_vrtmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\get_soundg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\histrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\hsv_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\jpeg_in_tiff_extract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\load2odbc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\loslas2ntv2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\magphase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\make_fuzzer_friendly_archive.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\mkgraticule.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2vrt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrupdate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_build_junction_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_dispatch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\rel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tigerpoly.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tile_extent_from_raster.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tolatlong.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_cloud_optimized_geotiff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_geoparquet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_gpkg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_jp2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\val_repl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr_spat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\wcs_virtds_params.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\osgeo_utils\samples
      running egg_info
      writing gdal-utils\GDAL.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to gdal-utils\GDAL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing entry points to gdal-utils\GDAL.egg-info\entry_points.txt
      writing requirements to gdal-utils\GDAL.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to gdal-utils\GDAL.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'gdal-utils\GDAL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      writing manifest file 'gdal-utils\GDAL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
      building 'osgeo._gdalconst' extension
      building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
      building 'osgeo._gdal_array' extension
      building 'osgeo._osr' extension
      building 'osgeo._gnm' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python
313\include -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wd1vnuyg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\in
clude\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/gdal_array_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions/gda
l_array_wrap.obj -DSWIG_PYTHON_SILENT_MEMLEAK
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python
313\include -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wd1vnuyg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\in
clude\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/osr_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions/osr_wrap.o
bj -DSWIG_PYTHON_SILENT_MEMLEAK
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python
313\include -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wd1vnuyg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\in
clude\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/gnm_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions/gnm_wrap.o
bj -DSWIG_PYTHON_SILENT_MEMLEAK
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python
313\include -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Include -IC:\Users\SJ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wd1vnuyg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\in
clude\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcextensions/gdalconst_wrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\extensions/gdalconst_wr
ap.obj -DSWIG_PYTHON_SILENT_MEMLEAK
      extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3452): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
      extensions/osr_wrap.cpp(3435): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_string.h': No such file or directory
      extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp(3377): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
      extensions/ogr_wrap.cpp(3406): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal
Failed to build gdal
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (gdal)



pip install whatever is simple when the library is pure python or the packager provides a precompiled package.  However, GDAL doesn't provide precompiled binaries.  If you really want to do this the hard way and compile the python bindings, you'll need to install GDAL binaries and have the GDAL source headers (this is what your compiler is complaining about) for the same GDAL version. And most/all Windows GDAL binary packages include the python bindings anyway, so there's not much point trying to get pip install gdal working.

Forgive me if this is noob question.

1 So if you use conda then you are stuck with conda shell. If you use OSGeo4W, then you are stuck with OSGeo4W shell to do the python coding? Can I not combine packages downloaded from venv and let's say conda together?

2 And how come OpenCV for python installation works easily? OpenCV for python is also just python binding for C++.

I use conda as it is easy, but you don't have to use conda or OSGeo4W. The simplest way if you want to use pip and your standard python install is the Gohlke wheels you linked to. OpenCV is easy because the package maintainer publishes source and precompiled packages/wheels ("Built Distributions"). GDAL does not, they only publish a source package to pypi. In fact, they don't publish any binaries at all, only source and containers - https://gdal.org/en/latest/download.html

How did Gohlke make his wheels then? Did he go all the hoops and precompile all the source code? I'm genuinely willing to pay to learn this skill.

Yes. The Gohlke wheels include a full gdal installation as well as the python bindings all compiled from source and packaged as a wheel

See also https://gitlab.com/mentaljam/gdal-wheels which I just found and some discussion at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/4352
